# Fragment was not found at expected path

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Eclipse shows this message below, but the file is there:

- Fragment "”main_header.jsp”" was not found at expected path /test-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/”main_header.jsp”

  ```
  test-webapp/
  `-- src
      |-- main
      |    |--webapp
      |    |   |--WEB-INF
      |    |   |   |--pages
      |    |   |   |   |--main.jsp
      |    |   |   |   |--main_header.jsp
  ```

main.jsp:

`<body>
   <jsp:include page=”main_header.jsp” />`

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `tree` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it me or your quotation marks seems strange ? `<jsp:include page=”main_header.jsp” />`

Try `<jsp:include page='main_header.jsp' />`
or `<jsp:include page="main_header.jsp" />`